# How can I download the CSV file from a Bank of England webpage using Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I would like to programmatically download the CSV file of the Official Bank Rate history on this page: https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/boeapps/database/Bank-Rate.asp
There is a link labelled CSV that is clicked to download the file.
I think clicking the link must run some javaScript that downloads the file as when I copy the link address it goes to: https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/boeapps/database/Bank-Rate.asp#.

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried until now?

Comment: you could use `selenium` to download that file.

Comment: Andrew Ryan, how would you use selenium? I tried but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to get that data as csv:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/boeapps/database/Bank-Rate.asp')[0]
df.to_csv('boe_rates.csv')
print(df)
```

EDIT: And here is another way, using Requests & Pandas (still avoiding the overheads of Selenium):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

url = 'https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/boeapps/database/Bank-Rate.asp'
df = pd.read_html(str(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text))[0]
df.to_csv('boe_rates.csv')
print(df)
```

In both scenarios, the result in terminal (also saved as a csv file) is the same:

```
    Date Changed    Rate
0   15 Dec 22   3.50
1   03 Nov 22   3.00
2   22 Sep 22   2.25
3   04 Aug 22   1.75
4   16 Jun 22   1.25
... ... ...
242 10 Mar 75   10.25
243 17 Feb 75   10.50
244 10 Feb 75   10.75
245 27 Jan 75   11.00
246 20 Jan 75   11.25
247 rows × 2 columns
```

You can find Pandas documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html).

Comment: I tried your code and it just errors with "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error"  
Is it possible to simulate pressing the "CSV" link/button on the BoE page to download the csv file?

Comment: Yes it's possible @JonathanRoberts - using Selenium. Of course, there is no need to use Selenium, given that my solution posted works. Try it again - sometimes it times out, but it works.

Comment: When I try your solution it instantly gets the error:
 urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error. There is no wait so it is not a timeout.

Comment: I think the 500 error might be expecting the data is there before the page has been downloaded? I got the same error with requests.get but when I added headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
    page = requests.get(url, timeout=5, allow_redirects=True, headers=headers) it returned the page. Is there anything similar for pd.read_html?

Comment: There you go @JonathanRoberts, I included another variant (of the same answer, essentially, but second one is also using Requests, with a custom header). Pick one, both work from my IP, and from several IPs over VPN. Good luck.